# Terminate Safari or Mail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, terminate

I am quite new here so I do not know many things. And the first thing I do not know is how to Terminate any running process programmatically, e.g. taping on the button; e.g. Mail or Safari.

If it is possible, do not show me the whole code, just the proper way I have to try.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to terminate them programatically?  Or you want to know how to close them via the UI?

Comment: I need to get them out from the list of running processes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that programmatically on the iOS with the public API.

Comment: Correct, an app cannot touch other apps directly.